# Unity Android notification

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-notifications

I am trying request permission for showing notifications on Anroid 13, however there isn't any pop-up showings and permission just declined.
Here is my code:

```
private async UniTaskVoid RequestNotificationPermission()
{
    var request = new PermissionRequest();
    await UniTask.WaitWhile(() => request.Status == PermissionStatus.RequestPending);
    this.Log($"Received notification permission status: {request.Status}");
}
```

I've tried to call this function before and after this call `AndroidNotificationCenter.RegisterNotificationChannel`, but it didn't help and in log I see that Status is denied.
Am I missing smth or should I somehow configure Android build?